# Invoking generic method from Main using reflection

Tags: c#

I am playing around with reflection. Not sure if anyone's come up with this scenario before:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MethodInfo definition = typeof(SafeClass).GetMethod("Print");
        MethodInfo constructed = definition.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
        constructed.Invoke(null, null);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

public class SafeClass
{
    public void Print<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

I got the error `Non-static method requires a target.`

If I make the `Print` method static, the call goes through. However, I am unsure how to invoke this call from inside static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Print<T>()` is an instance method, not a static method. It needs to be invoked on something.

For example, the code would be:

```
var sc = new SafeClass();
sc.Print<int>();
```

Just like you can't simply do this:

```
Print<int>();
```

You can't make reflection do it either. Either make print static, or change your code to this:

```
MethodInfo definition = typeof(SafeClass).GetMethod("Print");
MethodInfo constructed = definition.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
constructed.Invoke(new SafeClass(), null);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're basically doing the equivalent of the following, which won't work for obvious reasons.

```
null.Print<int>();
```

Either you intended to make `SafeClass.Print<T>()` static, or you need an instance of `SafeClass` to invoke the method on:

```
var mySafeClass = new SafeClass();
constructed.Invoke(mySafeClass, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that it requires some instance to complete call for this method. I have created object dynamically as well. So you can run any object if contains that method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object test=  Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SafeClass));     
        MethodInfo definition = typeof(SafeClass).GetMethod("Print");
        MethodInfo constructed = definition.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
        constructed.Invoke(test, null);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of Invoke should be the instance it self if the method is a instance method or constructor.

That's because when calling a instance method or constructor, the clr will implictly pass the instance as the first parameter to the function so that you can use `this` in the method.

in other language like python, this parameter is explicitly passed by the programmer